# Regex remove all divs which contain defined string

Tags: php, regex, html-lists

I need remove all li which contain

```
<img src="/mapfiles/
```

For example I have:

```
<li class="g"><span>Text</span></li>
<li class="g"><span>Text<img src=\"/mapfiles/iconA.png\"></span></li>**- I need remove it**
<li class="g"><span>Text<img src=\"/mapfiles/iconB.png\"></span></li>**- I need remove it**
<li class="g"><span>Text</span></li>
```

I tried use this:

```
preg_replace('!<li class="g">(.*)<img src="/mapfiles/(.*)</li>!is', '', $content);
```

But Regex match first < li class="g"> and last < /li> so removes all < li>, how can I write regex to find the nearest < /li> ?

Comment: Once again, we do not handle `HTML` with regex, we use HTML-parsers. Regex is not suitable for this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags for a discussion on regexes vs (x)html.

Comment: Once again the obligatory use a parser argument. Sometimes it is just not possible and regex is the only option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[THE PONY HE COMES...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)**

Use a parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$remove = $xpath->query("//li[.//img[starts-with(@src,'/mapfiles/')]]");
foreach($remove as $r) $r->parentNode->removeChild($r);
$output = substr($dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)),6,-7);
```